# Disable select options if hour less than actual hour

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was wondering if i could get some ideas of how to achieve this in jquery:

IDEA

Lets say the first option uses a hour range of 9 to 11 AM i need jquery to check the actual hour and if its greater than 11AM to add the `disabled` attribute to that option.

All options must reset when the day is over that means 12AM.

FORM

```
<select class="select" id="newfield3" name="newfield3">
<option disabled value="9:00 a 11:00 A.M">9:00 a 11:00 A.M</option>
<option value="11:00 a 1:00 P.M">11:00 a 1:00 P.M</option>
<option value="2:00 a 4:00 P.M">2:00 a 4:00 P.M</option>
<option value="4:00 a 6:00 P.M">4:00 a 6:00 P.M</option>
</select>
```

I'm a beginner in jquery so i really appreciate any help i get.

Comment: probably use the jquery `change()` function when the list is used so that when the state changes, it checks the time and does whatever else you need.

Comment: it should check onload instead of change any ideas?

Comment: I'm sure you realized this by now, but I just wanted to point out that the user can bypass this easily. Be sure to put some logic on the backend if you need to have this be confirmed before entry.

Comment: yes im aware of that, anyways tx for the Advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this is what i was looking for:

```
$("#newfield3 option").each(function() {
var $thisOption = $(this);
var HH = new Date().getHours();
var h1 = "9:00 a 11:00 A.M";
var h2 = "11:00 a 1:00 P.M";
var h3 = "2:00 a 4:00 P.M";
var h4 = "4:00 a 6:00 P.M";

if (HH >= 9 && HH < 17) {

if($thisOption.val() == h1) {

    if ( HH >= 10 ) {
            $thisOption.prop('disabled', true);
            $('#newfield3 option[value="' + h2 + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
    }

}   
if($thisOption.val() == h2) {

    if ( HH >= 12 ) {
            $thisOption.prop('disabled', true);
            $('#newfield3 option[value="' + h3 + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
            $('#newfield3 option[value="' + h2 + '"]').attr("selected", false);
    }

}   
if($thisOption.val() == h3) {

    if ( HH >= 15 ) {
            $thisOption.prop('disabled', true);
            $('#newfield3 option[value="' + h4 + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
            $('#newfield3 option[value="' + h3 + '"]').attr("selected", false);
    }

}
if($thisOption.val() == h4) {

    if ( HH >= 17 ) {
            $thisOption.prop('disabled', true);
    }

}

}

});
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try using

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();
```

and depending on the value of n , disable your `option`

Comment: I am using chrome jS console,but problem is there I need to write the code in one line.If I do enter,then code breaks.. :( JSfiddle has too many things,I want only JS console or any editor...

Comment: @Babai Google up notepad++ , it's a nice editor :-) Having too many options won't hurt much right ? You could use only the ones you need .. :-)

Comment: This might suit your needs as well https://github.com/remy/jsbin/blob/master/docs/running-your-own-jsbin.md

Comment: Can I run the JS code from notepad++ directly? means I don't need to embed it into the html code.. I am now in trouble to decide about the editor.. :(

Comment: @Babai : The only reason you are capable of doing on the fly javascript programming in chrome is because it already has the markup for the page,it injects your script changes to the DOM and that's why you can see the code changes instantly. I am afraid that you do need markup .

Comment: actually I am looking for editor,where I can write the code and run it and test it, like Neatbeans where we run java etc..